# How to activate usb port, -sc3 usb host driver not found

Tags: usb, connection-issues

I have an unbranded rck30sdk tablet running Android 4.1.1. I have run USB diagnostics, plus host controller which gives me the messages:

> sc3 usb host driver not found, root hub present, usb host mode is active.

How can i resolve this? Basically I want to connect my dslr to view/download images. I am reasonably computer literate, but have no experience of programming etc. I found one answer that mentioned inserting a new command via the system, permissions etc. I found these via x-plore, but only as a read-only option.

Can you give me any advice what I could do?